# Tinymce and filebrowser out the admin

Tags: django, tinymce, django-filebrowser

I'm working on a django project, and I'm trying to implement a textfield form field with tinymce and filebrowser (or another solution to upload images and insert them into my text field content). I have check the [aisayko package](https://github.com/aisayko/Django-tinymce-filebrowser) but seems like only run on admin site, and my form particularly, is not in the django admin site. how can I enable file uploads in my textfield usign rich text editor like tinymce? Thanks.